# What is the best way to make free phone calls from an iPod touch?

Tags: software-recommendation, ipod-touch

I want to be able to make free phone calls from an iPod touch. I've used Google Voice for my computer, but it doesn't work for an iPod touch. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

### [Talkatone](http://www.talkatone.com/) ([App Store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talkatone-free-calls-sms-texting/id397648381?mt=8)) Free

Allows you to make completely free phone calls using your Google Voice account. There are ads, but hey, it's free! I've had no trouble with it at all and I highly recommend it.

[image: Talkatone keypad]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

These are the ones that I mostly use, in order of relevance:

- Viber
- Skype
- Tango

Answer (score 2):

### [Nimbuzz](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nimbuzz-free-video-calls-messenger/id297574648?mt=8)

#### Nimbuzz to Nimbuzz

Free (video) calls (over 3G, 4G and WiFi) for iPhone to iPhone and iPhone to PC.

#### Connect with any SIP

You can connect to **any SIP provider**.
Get your own cheap provider for VoIP calls and connect it with Nimbuzz.

Nimbuzz also connects with:

- Yahoo! Messenger
- MSN Messenger
- AIM
- ICQ
- GoogleTalk
- Facebook
- MySpace
- Hyves

Comment: Does it make calls to actual phone numbers?

Comment: Only when set up with a SIP. I use [Freecall](http://www.freecall.com/en/calling-rates.html) which offers a limited amount of free minutes per week per unique IP.