# How can I turn an iPod touch into a functional mobile telephone?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Considering that [the iPhone is three times more expensive than the iPod touch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52938/the-iphone-is-over-3-times-more-expensive-than-the-ipod-touch-how-much-more-mar) and that the iPod touch is much thinner than the iPhone, it would be quite neat to use an iPod touch as to send and receive phone calls.

What would need to be done to enable an iPod Touch to send and receive phone calls (either Wi-Fi only or better interfacing to cellular data through an accessory)?

Comment: Would something like the "still-being-developed-for-sale" [MorphCase](http://www.indiegogo.com/morphcase) work?

Answer (score 3):

There are three steps that would need to be completed to enable an iPod Touch to act as a mobile telephone.

First, it would need to make phone calls. [The answers to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-free-phone-calls-from-an-ipod-touch) document how to place phone calls using an iPod Touch and VOIP. I personally have used [Talkatone](http://www.talkatone.com/), and find that it does work, but has some substantial lags, particularly at the beginning of the conversation.

Second, it would need to receive phone calls. (Note that this is a key difference between using an iPod Touch as a mobile telephone, as asked in your title, and a calling device, as asked in the body of the first version of your question!) This is a much more difficult prospect, as presumably you would want the device to be able to receive calls at any time, and not just when a particular app is running. It would appear that the program [Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/category/SKYPE_FOR_IPHONE/) is available for the iPod Touch and could be used to make and receive phone calls.

Finally, unlike the iPhone, the iPod Touch can only communicate with the rest of the world when it is connected to a WiFi network. A mobile hotspot like the [MiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiFi) carried with you could give the iPod Touch steady access to a WiFi network.

All that said, you'll end up paying for Skype in and out on top of paying for the data plan for the MiFi. It might be simpler and not a whole lot more expensive to just go with an actual iPhone.

In other words, it *can* be done to make an iPod Touch more like an iPhone, but that doesn't mean you'd want to, besides as a proof of concept.

Comment: I personally use [Pinger](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinger-text-free-+-call-free/id444741112?mt=8). It gives you a free phone number to send and receive calls, and incoming calls are free, as are all text messages.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand. If you are trying to save money on your phone bill AND have a fast stable wifi connection at home and work, you may try the following solution.

Use the TouchTone App with Google Voice or use Skype. Whichever one you have a preference for.  Skype can do video, but TouchTone will also send and receive text. There really isn't any reason you can't use both, but you will have two different phone numbers.

Buy one of those disposable prepaid phone. (yes, you will be carrying two devices) Those can be as cheap to use as $10 for 30 minutes which expires in 3 months if you don't use it. If you don't talk a lot between wifi connections, you will not be using many minutes.

Now forward to the number of your disposable phone if Skype or TouchTone doesn't answer.

NEVER give out the phone number for the disposable phone. And HIDE the caller ID from the disposable phone.

There you go. For as cheap as $40 a year in phone charges if you're careful.

If you talk a lot between WiFi.. this may not be for you. But if you're the sneaky college student type, if you can get your parents to shell out $80 a month for the phone bill, you come out WAY ahead. Like $920 a year. But don't do that, its mean.

Answer (score -2):

Unlock your iPod, and then you'll have the ability to turn your iPod touch into a Mobile phone. But you have to be careful unlocking, because it could damage the iPod if your not knowing what your doing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review